# Permitir acceso a páginas según el rol del usuario django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Hola tengo en mi aplicación 3 grupos de usuarios: secretaria, directora, técnico. Quiero mostrar en la barra de navegación la página correspondiente a cada rol una vez que el usuario de dicho rol haya iniciado sesión.

Este es el código de mi view:

```
def barra_navegacion(request):
    user = request.user
    g = user.groups.all()
    return render_to_response('gestiondoc/barra_panel.html', {'g':g},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Este es un fragmento del código de la barra:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    ...
{% if g == 'secretaria' %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'secretaria' %}">Panel Secretaria</a></li>
        {% elif g == 'tecnico' %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'tecdocente' %}">Panel Técnico Docente</a></li>
        {% elif g == 'directora' %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'directora' %}">Panel Directora</a></li>
    {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </li>
    {% else %}
             <li><a href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Entrar</a></li>
    {% endif %}
```

No carga el grupo del usuario a pesar de pertenecer a secretaria, g se muestra como una lista vacía.

También lo intenté poniendo en la base:

```
{% if 'secre' in request.user.perfil.grupo %}
  {% include "gestiondoc/barra_panel.html" %}
{% else %}
{% include "gestiondoc/barra_usuario.html" %}
```

Pero salta al else directamente.

Perfil es un modelo que tiene un método grupo:

```
  def grupo(self):
      return self.usuario.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Antes mostraba `[<Group:'secretaria>],` pero ahora ni siquiera reconoce el grupo del usuario. 
He intentado varias formas, pero no he tenido éxito. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo suelo usar algo así:

```
{% for groups in request.user.groups.values_list %}
      {% for group in groups %}
         {% if group == 'Secretaria'%}
               ...
         {%endif%}
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% ifequal user.groups.all.0 'Sales' %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

o en el modelo, en el metodo grupo(self) agrega property

```
@property
def grupo(self):
      return self.usuario.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
```